# Define class based on test case

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-4.0

Can some one tell me how to define the class Student such that the last test case is satisfied.
I could not understand how the method implementation of last function GetId().

```
public const int basicId = 12345;
public const int studentId = 88888;
public const string sampleName = "User Name";
[TestMethod] 
public void StudentIsInitializedCorrectly()
{
      User student = new Student(sampleName, basicId, studentId);
      Assert.AreEqual(sampleName, student.GetName());
      Assert.AreEqual(basicId, student.GetId());
      Assert.AreEqual(studentId, ((Student)student).GetId());
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand from the comments that you are working through some test-driven-development (TDD) exercises, and that you are having trouble understanding this example. So with that in mind, here's how I look at it:

1. The first thing that happens in the test is that while you are creating an instance of `Student`, it is being assigned to a variable that has the type `User`. There are different ways that this *could* work, but the most obvious explanation is that `User` is the base class, and that `Student` inherits `User`.
2. The next two statements call methods on the `student` variable directly. Since the type of this variable is `User`, those methods must exist in the `User` class. Again there are multiple ways that this could actually work, but the simplest is to assume that the values those methods need to return are in fact stored in the `User` class.

Those two points lead us to a `User` class that looks something like this:

```
class User
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly int _id;

    public User(string name, int id)
    {
        _name = name;
        _id = id;
    }

    public string GetName() { return _name; }
    public int GetId() { return _id; }
}
```

The above ensures that when we view the object instance through a variable having the type `User`, that we can still call the `GetName()` and `GetId()` methods, and get back the values we expect.

Now we come to the third and final test in the method. Note that this test casts the `student` variable to the class `Student` before calling the method. Note also that this method is expected to return the value in `studentId` and *not* the value in `basicId`, which is the value that the base class's `GetId()` method is supposed to return.

So we have the same method name, used on the same object instance, but which is supposed to behave differently depending on the *compile-time* type of the object (aka "static type"). This is as opposed to the *run-time* type, which is the actual type of the object.

Given that, we have to declare a new `GetId()` method in the `Student` class, and of course provide a way for it to return the different ID value that was used during the initialization of the object:

```
class Student : User
{
    private readonly int _id;

    public Student(string name, int basicId, int studentId)
        : base(name, basicId)
    {
        _id = studentId;
    }

    public new int GetId() { return _id; }
}
```

The one wrinkle is that given that we already know the `User` class has a method with this exact same name, you will be hiding that class's method with your new `GetId()` method. Thus, the `new` keyword is required to avoid any compile-time warnings.

My personal preference is to avoid method hiding *always*. It is pretty much always the wrong design choice, and should be used only when forced into it by some outside requirement.

(Note that the fields in the above classes are marked `readonly`. There's nothing in the test that requires this to be the case, but there's also nothing in the test that prevents it. My preference is to make fields `readonly` unless they can't be, hence the use of `readonly` here).

Comment: I do not have any implementation of Student class. I have to define it based on the test case above such that the test cases pass.

Comment: Well, the above should work...you might have to adjust the `base(name, basicId)` part depending on the declaration of `User` (do you have _that_?).

Comment: I don't have the declaration of either of two classes. I need to define both these two such that the test works.

Comment: Your posted question says you are only having trouble with the third test, i.e. _"...the method implementation of last function GetId()"_. Have you figured out your implementation of `User`? It seems reasonably straightforward to me, but if you are having trouble with that you should say so. You also should explain the context here; if it's a homework question, that would warrant some additional explanation of the answer (and of course you will want to consult with your teacher to make sure you've learned the concepts they want you to learn, since you didn't figure it out on your own).

Comment: Its one of the test case question I found in an exercise about test driven development. I could not figure it out.

Comment: That's fine. I didn't mean for you to fixate on the "homework" part of my comment. More important is the question about the `User` class and whether you have that much. If you do, you should include that in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75617/discussion-between-sravan-kumar-and-peter-duniho).

Comment: @SravanKumar: please see my edited answer, which now includes more details and an explanation of the `User` base class as well.

Comment: another option to make the User GetId method virtual and override it in the Student class to avoid using 'new'

Comment: @barakcaf: _"make the User GetId method virtual"_ -- that is exactly the wrong thing to do, as that would cause the second test to fail, because it then also would return the `studentId` value instead of the `basicId` value as it's supposed to. Given the test code here, hiding the method is the only appropriate option.